# Filtering by non-existing/atypical value of column causes slow performance

Tags: vertica

**FAST** (<0.1 s)

```
SELECT 1
FROM   sample
JOIN   unit ON sample.unit_key = unit.key
WHERE  sample.sample_id = 'http://example.com/foo';

+-JOIN HASH [Cost: 2K, Rows: 37] (PATH ID: 1)
|  Join Cond: (sample.UNIT_KEY = unit.KEY)
| +-- Outer -> STORAGE ACCESS for unit [Cost: 987, Rows: 3M] (PATH ID: 2)
| |      Projection: OLAPTEST_PRIVATE.UNIT_super
| |      Materialize: unit.KEY
| |      Runtime Filter: (SIP1(HashJoin): unit.KEY)
| +-- Inner -> STORAGE ACCESS for sample [Cost: 92, Rows: 37] (PATH ID: 3)
| |      Projection: OLAPTEST_PRIVATE.SAMPLE_super
| |      Materialize: sample.UNIT_KEY
| |      Filter: (sample.SAMPLE_ID = 'http://example.com/foo')
```

**SLOW** (> 2s)

```
SELECT 1
FROM   sample
JOIN   unit ON sample.unit_key = unit.key
WHERE  sample.sample_id = 'foo';

+-JOIN HASH [Cost: 5K, Rows: 1 (PREDICATE VALUE OUT-OF-RANGE)] (PATH ID: 1)
|  Join Cond: (sample.UNIT_KEY = unit.KEY)
| +-- Outer -> STORAGE ACCESS for sample [Cost: 90, Rows: 1 (PREDICATE VALUE OUT-OF-RANGE)] (PATH ID: 2)
| |      Projection: OLAPTEST_PRIVATE.SAMPLE_super
| |      Materialize: sample.UNIT_KEY
| |      Filter: (sample.SAMPLE_ID = 'foo')
| |      Runtime Filter: (SIP1(HashJoin): sample.UNIT_KEY)
| +-- Inner -> STORAGE ACCESS for unit [Cost: 987, Rows: 3M] (PATH ID: 3)
| |      Projection: OLAPTEST_PRIVATE.UNIT_super
| |      Materialize: unit.KEY
```

- Filter by 'foo' (non existing value in column) -> slow
- Filter by
  'xhttp://example.com/...' (non existing value in column) -> slow
- Filter
  by 'http://example.com/foo' (non existing value in column) -> fast
- Filter by 'http://example.com/123' (existing value in column) -> fast

With out the join the query is fast.

All values in column `sample_id` start with 'http://example.com/..'

I have analyzed statistics for all tables.

- `SAMPLE_ID VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL (AUTO encoding)`. No UNIQUE constraints, foreign keys etc.
- SAMPLE = 10k rows
- UNIT = 30M+ rows

What can there about `sample_id` column that causes filtering by it to be so slow for non-existing values? Filtering by other columns of the table (that have more varied values but few distinct values) all perform well.

Doing a similar query to another table (for example unit) that has also columns where the values are http-uris, does not have the similar performance effect.

What can I do? I do not want the application to be slow if the user gives a non-existing value...

We are still at Vertica 7, hoping to update to new cluster with newer version soon (at that point we can also create better projections for the tables).

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('', 'sample');` and post the results? Also, How large are the two tables? Thousands of rows, millions of rows, etc?

Comment: Profile the two queries here above and you will know exactly why one is faster than the other...

Comment: @A.Saunders Added table sizes above. Export objects: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/epiirainen/EboeMr   This is a new table so I have not run DBD on it yet.. sample.sampleId is not among order by

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SAMPLE` table is so small it should be `UNSEGMENTED`. Replace the segmented superprojection with an unsegmented one—this is just best practice anyway for such a small table. Also, having the `SAMPLE` table as `UNSEGMENTED` will eliminate global re-segmentation during the join.

Also, try putting `sample_id` as the first column in the `ORDER BY` clause of the projection. This will not create a mergejoin, but it will optimize the `WHERE` clause filter.

Let me know if that helps. If it does not, please include the entire explain plan with the new projection (including the Graphvis).

Comment: Unfortunately we are currently still running a one node "cluster" and that is why segmentation has not yet been defined for any tables. Sample table is small now, since this is staging version data. Amount will go up in production/in the future. (We will create a thee node cluster some time in the future, and at that point design better projections (w/ help of db designer) . Right now they super projections are what Vertica creates by default.)  In any case, I'm still curious about the performance impact of different values in a column...

Comment: Understood. I'd still create the projections as I have stated, that way when you move to a three node cluster, you won't have to change your DDL. Did you try ordering by `sample_id`, this aspect of my answer does not change whether you are on a single node cluster or a multi-node cluster. Try adding `sample_id` as the first column in the sort order, and see if that helps.